# How to prevent multiple GestureRecognizers.Tapped events from being handled

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, maui

So I have this MAUI app which allows the user to tap inside a border to load some data and open another ContentPage. To handle a user's tap, I added a GestureRecognizer to the border like this:

```
<Border>
  <Border.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="HandleBorderTapped"/>
  </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```

The `HandleBorderTapped` method looks like this:

```
private async void HandleBorderTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
  await LoadSomeDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Another ContentPage").ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

Now the `LoadSomeDataAsync` method takes a few seconds in which an impatient user might tap inside the border multiple times. Unfortunately this causes the app to open the ContentPage multiple times resulting in a navigation stack with many of those ContentPages. This I would like to avoid.

I tried blocking a second tap-handling by adding a bool like this:

```
private volatile bool isLoading;

private async void HandleBorderTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
  if (isLoading)
    return;

  isLoading = true;

  await LoadSomeDataAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("Another ContentPage").ConfigureAwait(true);

  isLoading = false;
}
```

This kind of helps but does not completely solve my problem. Now if I tap 5 times the ContentPage is opened only twice instead of 5 times. The ContentPage should only get opened once though...

Can anyone tell me how to prevent the GestureRecognizers from recognizing more than one tap? Or how to limit the simultaneous threads in my `HandleBorderTapped`-method or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not reset the flag to false until you navigate back to the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows how to **prevent multiple GestureRecognizers.Tapped events from being handled** with a minimal example of locking out the [Click Me] button on the .NET Maui Default App until some interval (in this case 2 seconds) from the last click. For the restartable time interval, some kind of watchdog timer is needed. A NuGet for a suitable timer can be added to project using instructions below. The second element of this solution is to have an overlay frame that covers the entire screen.

Ordinarily, the `IsVisible` property is `false`, and the overlay doesn't interfere with taps. Tap five times, you get a count of five.

[image: Modified .NET MAUI default app]

When the overlay is visible, the appearance is set to `BackgroundColor="DarkGray"` and `Opacity="0.25"` to give a "disabled" appearance to the screen when enabled. The `InputTransparent="False"` prevents the [Click Me] button from recognizing the taps, but only when the overly is set to `IsVisible`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="lock_out_tap_overlay.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <ScrollView>
            <VerticalStackLayout
                Spacing="25"
                Padding="30,0"
                VerticalOptions="Center">

                <Image
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                    Text="Hello, World!"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                    FontSize="32"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                    Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                    SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                    FontSize="18"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                <Button
                    x:Name="CounterBtn"
                    Text="Click me"
                    SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                    Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <CheckBox 
                        x:Name="checkboxIsLockOutMechanismEnabled"
                        IsChecked="False" 
                        Margin="10" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label 
                        Text="Enable Lock Out Mechanism" 
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>

            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <~--Overlay-->
        <Frame
            BackgroundColor="DarkGray" 
            Opacity="0.25"
            InputTransparent="False"
            IsVisible="{Binding IsLockedOut}">
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnOverlayTapped"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

---

C#

We use `{Binding IsLockedOut}` to hook this property up to the watchdog timer.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkboxIsLockOutMechanismEnabled.IsChecked)
        {
            ExtendLockout();
        }
        count++;
        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }
    WatchdogTimer _wdtOverlay = new WatchdogTimer();

    private void ExtendLockout()
    {
        _wdtOverlay.StartOrRestart(
            initialAction: () => IsLockedOut = true,
            completeAction: () => IsLockedOut = false);
    }

    public bool IsLockedOut
    {
        get => _isLockedOut;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isLockedOut, value))
            {
                _isLockedOut = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isLockedOut = false;

    private void OnOverlayTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExtendLockout();
    }
}
```

The result is that the UI will not be responsive for two seconds from the last time the screen was tapped. To be clear, if you sit and tap the screen once every second, you will "never" see a second tap for all eternity.

---

**Adding WatchdogTimer to Project**

There are various ways to make a watchdog timer. Here's the one I tested this answer with.

[image: watchdog timer on NuGet]

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/lock-out-tap-overlay.git) this sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *NumberOfTapsRequired* property like below.

```
<Border>
  <Border.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer 
        Tapped="HandleBorderTapped" 
        NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
  </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```

Reference link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap#create-a-tapgesturerecognizer

Comment: This might be useful if you wanted to _require_ the user to "tap 5 times", but this might be the opposite of the OP's problem?